# Bubble plot for COVID data using ggplot

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, geospatial, bubble-chart

I have a spreadsheet with Lat-Lon info of 14 regions in the Czech Republic (file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SiVhdCLRlDiz7IEVCpjLoKTcXFjO9AM4/view?usp=sharing)). I am trying to plot a map and put bubbles for the active cases in each of the regions. The lat-lon coords are for capital cities from each region.

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(rstudioapi)
library(dplyr)
library(ggmap)
library(mapproj)
library(viridis)

#----------------------------#
# Set your working directory #
#----------------------------#

setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path)) # RStudio IDE preferred
getwd() # Path to your working directory

# Country Boundary and the 14 regions within the Czech Republic

worldmap <- map_data("world")

worldmap2 <- dplyr::filter(worldmap, region %in% data.frame(countries = "Czech Republic"))

ggplot(worldmap2) + geom_polygon(aes(long,lat, group=group), col = "black", fill = "white", size = 1) + 
     labs(title = "COVID-19 in the Czech Republic", subtitle = "As of July 1, 2021", x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude", 
          caption = "(Source: Ministerstvo zdravotnictví České republiky)")
```

[image]

The sixth column of the spreadsheet has the active cases numbers. I am trying to get the numbers appear as bubbles on the above map. I tried the following but all dots are of the same size. How do I merge plot 1 and plot 2?

```
my_df <- read.csv("CZE_InitialSeedData.csv", header = T)

class(my_df)

my_sf <- st_as_sf(my_df, coords = c('Lon', 'Lat'))

my_sf <- st_set_crs(my_sf, value = 4326)

my_sf 

seedPlot <- ggplot(my_sf) + 
      geom_sf(aes(fill = InitialInfections))

seedPlot <- seedPlot + 
            scale_fill_continuous(name = "Active Cases", low = "pink", high = "red", na.value = "grey50")

seedPlot <- seedPlot + 
     theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.text.align = 1, legend.title.align = 0.5)

seedPlot
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to convert your data to a `sf` object. You could simply add your data to your map via a geom_point. To get bubbles map your column with the active cases on the `size` aesthetic:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(dplyr)

worldmap <- map_data("world")

worldmap2 <- dplyr::filter(worldmap, region == "Czech Republic")

base_map <- ggplot(worldmap2) +
  geom_polygon(aes(long, lat, group = group), col = "black", fill = "white", size = 1) +
  labs(
    title = "COVID-19 in the Czech Republic", subtitle = "As of July 1, 2021", x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude",
    caption = "(Source: Ministerstvo zdravotnictví České republiky)"
  )

base_map +
  geom_point(
    data = my_df,
    aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, color = InitialInfections, size = InitialInfections)
  ) +
  scale_color_continuous(name = "Active Cases", low = "pink", high = "red", na.value = "grey50") +
  scale_size_continuous(name = "Active Cases") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.text.align = 1, legend.title.align = 0.5)
```

[image]

**EDIT** As far as I get it you could add a north arrow and scale bar for non-sf coords. However, converting to an `sf` object will automatically pick the right units for the scale bar. To this end convert both the basemap and the points layer to an `sf` object like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(dplyr)
library(ggspatial)
library(sf)

worldmap <- map_data("world")

worldmap2 <- dplyr::filter(worldmap, region == "Czech Republic") %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>% 
  st_combine() %>% 
  st_cast("POLYGON")

base_map <- ggplot(worldmap2) +
  geom_sf(col = "black", fill = "white", size = 1) +
  annotation_north_arrow() +
  annotation_scale(location = "tl") +
  labs(
    title = "COVID-19 in the Czech Republic", subtitle = "As of July 1, 2021", x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude",
    caption = "(Source: Ministerstvo zdravotnictví České republiky)"
  )

my_df <- my_df %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("Lon", "Lat"), crs = 4326)

base_map +
  geom_sf(data = my_df, aes(color = InitialInfections, size = InitialInfections)) +
  scale_color_continuous(name = "Active Cases", low = "pink", high = "red", na.value = "grey50") +
  scale_size_continuous(name = "Active Cases") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.text.align = 1, legend.title.align = 0.5)
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
my_df <- structure(list(Location = c(
  "Prague", "CentralBohemian", "SouthBohemian",
  "Plzen", "KarlovyVary", "UstinadLabem", "Liberec", "HradecKralove",
  "Pardubice", "Vysocina", "SouthMoravian", "Olomouc", "Zlin",
  "Moravian-Silesian"
), Lat = c(
  50.083333, 50, 49.083333, 49.7475,
  50.230556, 50.658333, 50.685584, 50.209167, 49.951136, 49.6079,
  49.363161, 49.593889, 49.29786, 49.988449
), Lon = c(
  14.416667,
  14.533333, 14.666667, 13.3775, 12.8725, 14.041667, 14.537747,
  15.831944, 15.795636, 15.580728, 16.643175, 17.250833, 17.393135,
  17.464759
), InitialVaccinated = c(
  252944L, 159560L, 93490L, 82014L,
  40129L, 104454L, 59442L, 82074L, 65060L, 66325L, 165250L, 89116L,
  80125L, 159490L
), InitialExposed = c(
  1380L, 1274L, 1048L, 500L,
  50L, 1098L, 506L, 42L, 492L, 820L, 1406L, 1090L, 1116L, 2404L
), InitialInfections = c(
  690L, 637L, 524L, 250L, 25L, 549L, 253L,
  21L, 246L, 410L, 703L, 545L, 558L, 1202L
), InitialRecovered = c(
  181947L,
  226944L, 97405L, 95944L, 43882L, 120416L, 79029L, 102835L, 91729L,
  78308L, 151627L, 90887L, 89163L, 174251L
), InitialDead = c(
  2736L,
  3421L, 1978L, 1912L, 1484L, 2523L, 1280L, 1811L, 1437L, 1375L,
  3412L, 1709L, 1594L, 3521L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -14L
))
```

Comment: Why `region %in% data.frame(countries = "Czech Republic")` rather than `region == "Czech Republic"` for the filter condition? - I'm curious, not having seen this formulation before.

Comment: @Peter. Lol. Me neither. Just copied and pasted from the OP without having a closer look at the filter condition.

Comment: @stefan thank you for your guidance of creating the bubble chart. The reason I attempted to convert my data to a sf object was to add a north arrow and scale bar but it kept giving me an error/warning. I even installed ggspatial and added + annotation_scale() + annotation_north_arrow() to the baseplot both of which are warning me "True north is not meaningful without coord_sf()". Is there anyway to add a north arrow and scale bar to the my_df as you coded?

Comment: Hi @Ash. I just made an edit to add a north arrow and a scalebar. Best S.

Comment: @stefan Thank you so much for your code. I have adopted that for the Czech Republic and another LMIC but what I am struggling with is to add boundaries for states/provinces on the existing ggplot for example the Czech Republic has 14 regions. Is there a easy way add those internal Level1 country boundaries?

Comment: Hi @Ash. In principle this is not a big deal. All you need is a shapefile or ... containing the state geometries. Not sure whether there is an offical source for cartographic data in the Czech Republic. But one option to get such data would be https://gadm.org/.